# Graph API: Using $filter with schema extensions data not working when request sent as part of a batch operation

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

According to the [Graph API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-schema-groups), making a GET request to get groups with extension data that includes a filtered response is acceptable.  For example, according to the doc referenced the following request should be valid:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${id}/memberOf?$filter=graphlearn_courses/courseId eq ‘123’&$select=displayName,id,description,graphlearn_courses
```

This works when making the request as a singleton but fails and returns no response when the same request is made as part of a batch request:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "requests": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/users/${id}/memberOf?$filter=graphlearn_courses/courseId eq ‘123’&$select=displayName,id,description,graphlearn_courses"
    }
    ...
  ]
}
```

Can I fix this myself, or do I need MS support?

Comment: FYI, this fails with both /v1.0 and /beta versions of the Graph API.

Comment: I have a different behavior with you. Could you share a screenshot of the successful call of singleton? (including the full request and response)

Comment: Please note that Schema extensions (legacy) are not returned with $select statement, but are returned without $select. So i would recommend you to try that and see if it helps. It's documented in Microsoft Graph API limitations - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#delta-query

Comment: Do you still need help on this issue? If yes, please share more details I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Schema extensions (legacy) are not returned with $select statement, but are returned without $select. So i would recommend you to try that and see if it helps. Documentation available @ [Microsoft Graph API limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#delta-query).